# Content editors accessing content on a different site

Tags: jquery, content-editor-web-part

I have a content editor which links to a text file on a fellow site (same root directory) which formats the list on the page. when I used this site as a template for a site on a different root the content editor didn't display correctly because I believe SharePoint doesn't allow editors to access files on a different root.

Is there a way around this does anyone know, I tried having a file on the SharePoint site which then called various files on the external site and it worked for the js queries but I'm not sure how to represent the other code such as below and then if I can call it.

```
<style type='text/css'>

.ms-vh-div[DisplayName='Programme']{width:100px;}
.ms-vh-div[DisplayName='Group']{width:100px;}
.ms-vh-div[DisplayName='Workstream']{width:100px;}

</style>
```

The reason I can't just have this all of the code on the site is that I want to be able to make updates to one file and the updates cascade to all SharePoint sites